# How to write a multidimensional array into a fits with proper axes formatting?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, fits

I have a list of two arrays which returns two arrays like the following:

```
mainarray = array1, array2
```

The size of `array1` is let's say `50`. However, `array2` is multidimensional of the shape `[100, 100, 50]`, where say `[100, 100]` is the sky coordinates, and for each sky coordinate we have `50` values corresponding to `array1`. Now I want to write this data into a fits file, with a proper formatting of first two axes corresponding to `[100, 100]` data points, second axes corresponding to [50, 50] values of `array1` and `array2[axis=2]`. What is the proper way of doing this? Will just

```
    hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(mainarray)
    hdu.writeto('skymap.fits', clobber = True)
```

work?

Comment: Did you try it?  If not, what went wrong?  In general probably not--FITS files can contain one or more array each in a separate HDU (Header Data Unit--an array plus metadata pair).  Each array is heterogeneous, and you can just combine two differently shaped arrays into a single HDU.  However, you could write each array to a separate HDU.  Or, it's possible based on your explanation that a table might possibly be appropriate as well.  I would worry about the specific mechanics of writing your data to a FITS file, and first better explain what your data is representing abstractly.

Comment: Actually, it worked. I need to be careful while manipulating the data cube, but storage works perfectly.

Comment: Does it really though?  If you've explained what you're doing correctly, it means you're passing a tuple of two differently-shaped `ndarray`s into the `PrimaryHDU` constructor.  If, by some miracle, that didn't crash immediately, it will crash eventually since that's not a sensible data structure for a single FITS HDU.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried this and it crashed immediately like I expected.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it again, and it crashed. Interesting that it seemed to work first time, but when I looked at the fits file in DS9, it did not display anything, so for some reason it did not show any error even though it was not working the first time.

Comment: So maybe you can be a bit clearer about what the end result is you're trying to get to and maybe what the purpose is. What kind of data are you trying to represent?